# Where is the oscillator in the 555 chip provided here?

Tags: oscillator, datasheet, timer, 555, bjt

I have tried a while to understand how the 555 chip is built. I opened the datasheet of TI available  here :
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf

Anyway this is the schematic from the datasheet [image]

how do i understand it :

Q1 - Q6 : a current source ? why to use 6 BJTs and not 4? ("current mirror" ?)

Q7 - Q13 : current source as well?!

Q15 - Q16 : what are they for?

Q17 - Q22 : is it a kind of inverter???

Q23 - Q24 : what is this part role?

Q27 - Q28 : what is this part role?

Q25 and Q14 : the only one that understood (closing Q_23 and set output to HIGH Z)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind the schematic shown in the datasheet is probably not exact.  Think of it more as a conceptual description.

Q1-Q6 and Q7-Q10,Q12-Q13 are each differential inputs, the front ends of comparators.  Notice that one side of each comparator is brought out and the other is either at 1/3 or 2/3 of the supply.  Q15-16 is a current mirror.  The way it is hooked up it provides a lot of gain to the left comparator.  The stuff right of that is mostly logic to produce the right signal in the right cases and to control the discharge output.  The stuff way at the right is the main output pin driver.

Comment: the design is exact isn't it? just the sizes and resistors value are different, right?

Comment: In the diagram of the 555, I'm a little confused by the reset pin, and by the "ground" connection of Q24.  Is the collector of Q24 supposed to be connected to the GND pin, even though it's the only thing connected to a "ground" symbol, or is that a substrate connection, or what?  As for reset, it looks as though pulling RESET weakly low would cause the collector of Q25 to source current to the base of Q14 but pulling it strongly low would pull the emitter of Q25 to a diode drop above ground, meaning the Q25 couldn't source current to Q14.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably simpler to explain by showing how to build an astable multivibrator (like a 555 circuit) from a raw op-amp:

[image]

The operation is explained in the [source I stole the diagram from](http://newton.ex.ac.uk/teaching/cdhw/Electronics2/PHY2003-11.pdf).

But basically, the op-amp is operating as a comparator. Assume the output starts out high (V6 ~ Vcc), but capacitor C1 is discharged. The output will stay high as C1 slowly charges through R3. When C1 charges up to Vcc / 2 (the value set by the R2-R1 divider), suddenly the (-) input is higher than the (+) input, and the output will go low (to ~Vee, which must be below ground). Now the output will stay low while C1 slowly discharges through R3. When C1 is discharged to Vee / 2, the comparator is triggered again and the output goes back high, and so on.

You can follow through the source link to see how to modify the circuit for monostable operation and a couple of other variants.

Note that in the 555 circuit, R3 and C1 are external components you have to provide, and the circuit is also modified to operate from a single supply.